# incorrect output from for loop inside function

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I've created a simple loop to calculate the efficiency of some simulated data. It performs perfectly well whilst as a loop:

```
NSE_cal <- NULL

for(i in 1:6) {
 Qobs <- flowSummary_NSE1[[i]][[3]]
 Qsim <- flowSummary_NSE1[[i]][[1]]
 object_cal <- NSEsums("NSE")
 NSE_cal <- c(NSE_cal, object_cal)
 }

#NSE_cal
#[1] 0.8466699 0.7577019 0.8128499 0.9163561 0.7868013 0.8462228
```

However, I want to apply this loop quite a few times - I need to vary the object `flowSummary_NSE#` and I have four different transformation types to apply. As a start, I put the loop inside a function, with only `transformation` needing to be specified, like so:

```
badFunction <- function(transformation){

 NSE_cal <- NULL

 for(i in 1:6) {
  Qobs <- flowSummary_NSE1[[i]][[3]]
  Qsim <- flowSummary_NSE1[[i]][[1]]
  object_cal <- NSEsums(transformation)
  NSE_cal <- c(NSE_cal, object_cal)
 }
  print(NSE_cal)
}

 badFunction("NSE")
 # [1] 0.8462228 0.8462228 0.8462228 0.8462228 0.8462228 0.8462228
```

The function has exactly the same information input as in the for loop on its own, except, for some reason, it outputs the same value for each case of `i`.

It is clear that I have done something wrong. But as far as I can see, it must be something simple contained to the function itself. However, incase it is an error elsewhere, I have attached the code that generates the necessary data and dependent functions ([here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6abef5573a44868b91fc249a1c04ada320170131160221/9c41a2))

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass objects into the nested function as arguments.

In your function_NSEsums.r script change the first line to `NSEsums <- function(i, Qobs, Qsim) {`

In your example_script.r change your code to the following:

```
badFunction <- function(transformation){

  NSE_cal <- NULL

  for(i in 1:6) {
    Qobs <- flowSummary_NSE1[[i]][[3]]
    Qsim <- flowSummary_NSE1[[i]][[1]]
    object_cal <- NSEsums(transformation, Qobs = Qobs, Qsim = Qsim)
    NSE_cal <- c(NSE_cal, object_cal)
  }

  print(NSE_cal)

}

badFunction("NSE")

[1] 0.8466699 0.7577019 0.8128499 0.9163561 0.7868013 0.8462228
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look in the dependent materials; I was sure I had gone through every single part already. The solution seems rather obvious now! I'll add that to my list of things to try the next time a for loop in a function isn't working

Comment: Your very welcome. Just FYI your bad function wouldn't have output 0.846.. six times if you cleared the global environment before running it. It was pulling Qobs and Qsim from there hence the same value each time.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! I always ran the plain loop before it so that I could confirm the output was correct. I'll add that to the list of things to try when troubleshooting next time. Thanks for your excellent advice